# problem installing R packages because the default library is unwriteable

Tags: r

I am trying to install packages in R studio and when I press "install" it gives me a message asking me if I would like to create a personal library to install packages into. I can't press "yes" so when i press "no" it gives me a message saying "Unable to install packages because the default library is unwriteable" . Any help on why that happens and what should I do next?

Comment: suggestion: open R native or in terminal. install.packages(). see if you can type 'y' there.

Comment: What operating system is your computer running?